# How to perform 3+1 decomposition of spacetime with xTensor?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, physics, xact

I am new to xTensor. I would like to perform 3+1 decomposition of spacetime with xTensor, but I do not have any clue. Although in xTensorDoc.nb, the author gave some hint, I absolutely have no idea of how to proceed. There is also one section on the induced metric in xTensorDoc.nb, but it does not serve my purpose. I would like to study a certain kind of $U(1)$ field in 3+1 decomposition, and the "electric field" plays an special role as it appears explicitly in the Lagrangian density. So somehow, I need split the "electric field" part from other parts of the $U(1)$ field strength $F_{ab}$.

Probably, I need also use xCoba to express everything in component form, but I still do not have any idea.

Please help me out! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add links to xTensor and Mathematica code of loading it and doing computations with it.

Comment: @AntonAntonov In http://www.xact.es/index.html, you can get the full package containing xTensor and xCoba. Of course, you can download xTensor from http://www.xact.es/xTensor/index.html and xCoba from http://www.xact.es/xCoba/index.html. I have no Mathematica code to paste, because I have no idea how to implement.